# extracting data from a hash of arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I'm new to ruby and working on a large data project and I'v got a nooby question.

I'v got a hash containing data of sales which is sorted by stores id:

```
hash = Hash.new(Array.new))
Sale.all.each {|sale| hash[sale.store_id].push( JSON.parse(sale.data)['items']) }
```

Now, I want to run over each `store_id` and get every `item.promo_code = 24` and say how many item are there for each `store.id`.

Here is the data structure of the array inside of each key:

```
hash => 1 : Array [[{DATA,DATA,DATA}{DATA,DATA,DATA}]]
```

How would this be done in ruby?

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT:**

I decided to attack this problem from a different angle

```
Sale.all.each {|sale| arr[sale.store_id] +=1 if (JSON.parse(sale.data)['items'].each{|item| item['buy_promotion_code']} == 24)  }
```

doesn't get me anything i get `arr[#] = 0` all the time help : (

Comment: can you post the sample of `hash` after initializing?

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend helped me with this.

he showed me the count function which simplified all this mess

this is the line that worked for me :

```
Sale.all.each {|sale| arr[sale.store_id] +=  (JSON.parse(sale.data)['items'].count {|item|  item['buy_promotion_code'] == "-1"}) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result_hash = {}

hash.each do |key, array|
  result_hash[key] = array.find_all({|item| item.promo_code = 24}).length
end
```

Comment: this seems like its supposed to work but i still get result_hash[key]= nil :(

Comment: It may relative to the data structure inside the hash instance. According to your description the data inside the hash may have the structure like this. {:1 => [{:promo_code => 1}, {:promo_code => 2}, ...], :2 => [{:promo_code => 1}, {:promo_code => 24}, ...], ...}. Check it out of your hash instance and see whether this is right.

Comment: i posted more info maybe you can help me ? : )

Answer (score 0):

```
result_hash = {}

hash.each do |key, array|
  result_hash[key] += 1 if array[0] == 24
  puts array
end
```

where array[0] should give the value of promo_code of each item in the array.